# Appending columns from two tables in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, vbscript

I have two MS Access tables:

tableA

```
num   state
1     12
2     13
1     11
3     12
```

tableB

```
num   stateA   stateB
1      12      11
1      12      11
2      13      12
2      12      11
1      12      11
1      15      11 
3      12      11
```

How can I create a third table which will have only one column num - appended from two tables ... other columns from two tables ignored:

```
tableC
num
1
2
1
3
1
1
2
2
1
1
3
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: tableC violates first normal form (1NF) because it doesn't have a key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
SELECT tableA.num
FROM tableA
UNION ALL
SELECT tableB.num
FROM tableB
```

Comment: Change it to tableB in the second select and I'll give you the deserved vote (-:

Comment: Note that UNION ALL will return all values of num, whereas UNION will remove all duplicates. Can be handy dependent on what you need.

Answer (score 1):

To create a new table, the Union query above can be used as a subquery:

```
SELECT x.Num  INTO New  FROM (
   SELECT tableA.num
   FROM tableA
   UNION ALL
   SELECT tableB.num
   FROM tableB ) As x
```